# iTextsharp CMYK colors result in another color

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, cmyk

I'm working on a little project where i need to create a pdf containging some table with some text. This table is supposed to have a certain background color. For testing sake i've simplified my code to this:

```
            using(var output = new MemoryStream())
            using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 120))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                
                document.Open();

                var table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("blah blah blah")) {BackgroundColor = new CMYKColor(11, 8, 1, 0)});
                document.Add(table);

                document.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\test.pdf", output.GetBuffer());
            }
```

As you see i've set the background color. Yet somehow it's resulting in a completely different color then i'm expecting.

[image: The color seems different somehow]

Can you help me figuring out what i am doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: I created the Pdf from your sample code and compared the background color to the same values on [colorizer](http://colorizer.org/) and cannot make out (much) of a difference. Could it be that your display is to blame? (I can't see the linked image because the site is blocked on my current net)

Comment: What's hard is that the sample image that you provided is in RGB. Can you provide a linked JPEG/TIFF for what you expect it to look like as well as a PDF?